# How far away is ROS/Gazebo 1.9?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

"Tutorials/1.9/Installing gazebo ros" Packages says:
"Warning: These instructions use the latest development version of Gazebo because we are currently making a major push to revamp the ROS integration with Gazebo. Until Gazebo 1.9 is released mid summer 2013, these tutorials are considered 'Advanced' because they require you to build from source somewhat unstable code."

It's mid summer 2013.  When will a released version of ROS with Gazebo be available? Is it better to wait or to struggle with "unstable code"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3471/how-far-away-is-ros/gazebo-1.9?/) by [John Nagle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/395/john-nagle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 1.9 will be released this week. And will be in ROS Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0